# Uncaught: Call to SetUploadURL failed

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I am trying to set dynamic value to uploadify. But it is giving me the error mentioned in the question.

What I want to set a dynamic value to `uploader` option of uploadify. So I did the following:

```
$(function() {
    var uploader = $('.path').val() + '/uploadservlet?key=' + $('.key').val();

    $('.uploadify').uploadify({                        
        'buttonText' : 'Browse',
        'fileSizeLimit': 0,
        'swf': '../uploadify/uploadify.swf'
    });                    
    $('.uploadify').uploadify('settings', 'uploader', uploader);
});
```

But it is giving me the aforesaid error. Also I have tried to call as:

```
'onInit'   : function(instance) {
    $('.uploadify').uploadify('settings', 'uploader', uploader);
}
```

But no luck. Any pointer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met this problem, too. The error message is misleading.

I debug the `js` and figure out that the source exception is `__flash__argumentsToXML` not defined. And the root cause is that the `swf` is not ready when calling this function.

And I move the setting code into `onUploadStart` handler and it is ok.